# Custom Knight dialer solution's time and space complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, programming-challenge

I recently solved the Knight Dialer problem but I'm not quite sure if I got the time complexity right; hence I'm requesting the following:

1) Time and space complexity review and explanation on why so.

The question says:

> *Imagine you place a knight chess piece on a phone dial pad. This chess piece moves in an uppercase “L” shape: two steps horizontally
>   followed by one vertically, or one step horizontally then two
>   vertically: Pay no attention to the poorly-redacted star and pound
>   keys Suppose you dial keys on the keypad using only hops a knight can
>   make. Every time the knight lands on a key, we dial that key and make
>   another hop. The starting position counts as being dialed.
>   **How many distinct numbers can you dial in N hops from a particular starting position?***

Knight dialer: (movs map has all the possible movements for every number)

```
private static int knightDialer(int start, int nth, Map<Integer, Integer[]> movs, Set<Integer> res) {

    if (nth == 0) {

        return 0;
    }

    Integer[] validMoves = movs.get(start);

    for (Integer mov : validMoves) {

        if (!res.contains(mov)) {

            res.add(mov);
            knightDialer(mov, nth - 1, movs, res);
        }

    }

    return res.size();      

}
```

If I'm missing something important for the review, please let me know.

Thanks.

---

Test Case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int start = 0;

    int nth = 3;

    System.out.println(knightDialer(start, nth));
    System.out.println();
}

private static int knightDialer(int start, int nth) {

    Map<Integer, Integer[]> movs = getAllMoves();

    Set<Integer> res = new HashSet<>();
    res.add(start);

    return knightDialer(start, nth, movs, res);

}

private static Map<Integer, Integer[]> getAllMoves() {

    Map<Integer, Integer[]> movs = new HashMap<>();

    movs.put(1, new Integer[]{ 6, 8 });
    movs.put(2, new Integer[]{ 7, 9 });
    movs.put(3, new Integer[]{ 4, 8 });
    movs.put(4, new Integer[]{ 3, 9, 0 });
    movs.put(6, new Integer[]{ 1, 7, 0 });
    movs.put(7, new Integer[]{ 2, 6 });
    movs.put(8, new Integer[]{ 1, 3 });
    movs.put(9, new Integer[]{ 2, 4 });
    movs.put(0, new Integer[]{ 4, 6 });

    return movs;
}
```

Comment: What are the two tasks, and do they have anything to do with each other? If not, please post them as two separate questions. Also add the [tag:java] language tag.

Comment: Will do. Then I'm going to ask another question for the ugly numbers and leave this solely for the knight dialer algorithm.

Comment: My reading of the problem statement would be to find out how many _sequences_ of digits of length `n` can be produced starting from any particular position. Can you clarify the intention of the code and explain how you've solved the problem?

Comment: The intention of the code is to count all possible moves (keys dialed) for n hops. If you start at 1, then you can hop to either 6 or 8, so we can count those hops (by adding them into the set) and decrement the value of n prior calling the recursive method. This would repeat until n == 0.
The general idea is to count how many keys can be dialed in n hops (start point being counted too). The loop is there because if you can make 2 different hops, that means 2 method calls, so the loop is going through the Integer[] and picking the values individually.

Comment: The "test case" doesn't actually seem to do any tests, except to verify that no exceptions are thrown. Did the source of the question include any test cases (input and expected output)? Like VisualMelon, I would expect that `161616` would be a valid 6-digit number. I would also interpret the question as asking how many (N+1)-digit numbers can be dialled, not how many numbers *up to* N+1 digits.

Comment: The test case should execute the recursive method which solves the knight dialer problem. If you execute that main method, it should print an integer. The current specified case is 2 moves starting at zero. To test it, I just counted manually and then used the program to check if the output I got manually was right. The article is this: https://hackernoon.com/google-interview-questions-deconstructed-the-knights-dialer-f780d516f029. 
As for my understanding since 161616 are not distinct numbers, from that sequence I'd just take 16 and ignore the rest.

Comment: I might got the problem wrong and what I understood of "distinct numbers" is not what the problem meant, but still it's doing what I understand was needed, so it solves a problem. If that was the case, is that a problem to know what this snippet's time complexity is?

Comment: The article lists `6–1–6`, `6–7–6`, and `6–0–6` as valid three-digit sequences. (It also makes me worry about the ignorance of Google interviewers).

Comment: I actually have both solutions: this one and one that counts unique sequences. The algorithm is pretty much the same. Still unsure on its times complexities though.